# Can I substitute vanilla powder for cocao in a quinoa cake recipe

Tags: baking

ingedients:

- 2 cups quinoa
- 1/3/cup milk
- 4 lg eggs
- 1 tsp vanilla extract
- 3/4 cup butter
- 1 1/2/cup granulated sugar
- 1 cup unsweetened cocao pwdr
- 1 1/2 tsp baking powder
- 1/2 tsp baking soda
- 1/2/tsp salt

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SA! Have a look at the [Tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Center](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help) when you get a chance. Why do you want to make this substitution?

Comment: This recipe won't produce a cake - unless you mean quinoa flour. And what do you mean by "vanilla powder"? Pure synthetic vanillin, ground vanilla seeds, or something else?

Comment: the quinoa is cooked and then mixed in a blender with the wet ingredients. its 2 cups of cooked quinoa.

Answer (score 4):

Typically no. You need much more cocoa powder for a chocolate cake than you need vanilla powder for a vanilla cake. Adding a cup of vanilla would be both very expensive and very overwhelming in terms of flavour. And the vanilla doesn't have the same chemical properties as cocoa. Cocoa has a bit of fat in it, so a substitute should include some fat.

Comment: i see that some vanilla powder is mixed with sugar. could i use some of that, reduce the granulated sugar and add gluten free flour to make up the volume of the cocao.  not sure what to do about the fat in cocao. some applesauce maybe?

Comment: @joefromnc Here's a different question that discusses how to substitute cocoa powder: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22420/how-should-i-alter-a-chocolate-cake-recipe-to-make-plain-flavoured-cake#:~:text=You%20cannot%20simply%20replace%20the,Is%20more%20acidic